# How do I create list of URL strings using a dataframe/series of values?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, url

I have a series of values `IDs` that I convert to a dataframe `dfA` that outputs as:

|  | IDs |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ID_3456789065 |
| 1 | ID_4546567657 |
| 2 | ID_1765768878 |

I'm trying to convert `dfA['IDs']` into a string list of URLs that outputs as:

```
'https://api.names.io/v1/ids/ID_3456789065/IDAccounts'
'https://api.names.io/v1/ids/ID_4546567657/IDAccounts'
'https://api.names.io/v1/ids/ID_1765768878/IDAccounts'
```

This gets me what I want if I manually enter an ID:

```
acctID = 'ID_3456789065'
f'https://api.names.io/v1/ids/{acctID}/IDAccounts'
```

Outputs:

```
'https://api.names.io/v1/ids/ID_3456789065/IDAccounts'
```

I keep getting the wrong output or an error when I try looping through `dfA` using different versions of this:

```
urlList=[]

for i in dfA:
  acctID = dfA[i]
  urlList = f'https://api.names.io/v1/ids/{acctID}/IDAccounts'
  urlList.append(urlList)
```

Outputs:

```
https://api.names.io/v1/ids/0    ID_3456789065
1    ID_4546567657
2    ID_1765768878
Name: data_bettor, dtype: object/IDAccounts
```

I've tried .concat too and that throws `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension that iterates over the "IDs" column:

```
out = [f'https://api.names.io/v1/ids/{acctID}/IDAccounts' for acctID in df['IDs']]
```

Output:

```
['https://api.names.io/v1/ids/ID_3456789065/IDAccounts',
 'https://api.names.io/v1/ids/ID_4546567657/IDAccounts',
 'https://api.names.io/v1/ids/ID_1765768878/IDAccounts']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
urlList = list('https://api.names.io/v1/ids/' + df['IDs'] + '/IDAccounts')
print(urlList)

# Output
['https://api.names.io/v1/ids/ID_3456789065/IDAccounts',
 'https://api.names.io/v1/ids/ID_4546567657/IDAccounts',
 'https://api.names.io/v1/ids/ID_1765768878/IDAccounts']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) on the `IDs` column and use [`to_list`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html) to get a list out of the series:

```py
 df["IDs"].apply(lambda acctID: f'https://api.names.io/v1/ids/{acctID}/IDAccounts').to_list()
```

This outputs:

```py
['https://api.names.io/v1/ids/ID_3456789065/IDAccounts',
 'https://api.names.io/v1/ids/ID_4546567657/IDAccounts',
 'https://api.names.io/v1/ids/ID_1765768878/IDAccounts']
```